# Switch Root Page in Ionic 2 Application

Tags: javascript, navigation, ionic2, nav

I have a problem in switching root page in ionic 2 application.
My application has 2 pages called `LoginPage` and `HomePage`. When the user clicks logout button, he will have to navigate to LoginPage, and after successful login, he will have to navigate to HomePage.

I tried following:

This is my logout function which is in `app.component.ts`

```
public logOut() {
    this.nav.setRoot(LoginPage);
}
```

This is my login function in `login.page.ts`

```
public login() {
    this.navController.setRoot(HomePage);    
}
```

But, the problem is... 
If the user logout and login for the first time, it works fine. For the second time, the Homepage initiates twice. That means `ngOnInit()` method on HomePage gets called twice. For the third login, HomePage initiates three times.

When I debug the code, I found that the login function is getting called three times for the third login. But I couldn't find how it is getting called three times.

So now, I can't imagine why is this happening. Please anyone can give me an idea to overcome this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it setting to root page though. As in there should not be a back button once a Rootpage is set.

Comment: the problem is not with a back button. I navigate to the login page using logout function as I described above. :/

Comment: Can you try: lets say you are in home page. Do a `this.navController.pop(HomePage)` first followed by `this.navController.setRoot(LoginPage)`